# How to find column in a sparse matrix with only one value set

Tags: matrix, julia

I have a large sparse matrix `M`. How can I find the index of a column in the matrix which has only one value set? That is exactly one non-zero value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `findall(==(1), diff(M.colptr))` should do it (to find all columns with one stored value).

Comment: Thank you. This wasn't as obvious as it might have been!

Comment: Yeah, it is perhaps a bit terse. More explicit might be `findall(i -> length(nzrange(M, i)) == 1, 1:size(M, 2))`